# JavaScript incorrect sorting of data in the table HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html, python-3.x

The table has columns with dates and when I need to sort the data by date and I see that they are sorted incorrectly.

The same problem with another column, it contains information such as string

[image]

**Columns:**

***string***

[image]

***date***

[image]

**app.py**

```
        software_data = []
        software_data.append(software.app_id)
        software_data.append(current_user.timezoned(software.workflow.started).\
                strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
        result = {"data": software_data}
        return jsonify(result)
```

**list.html**

```
{% block page_block_content %}
    <table id="portfolio" class="portfolio table no-margin">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="appid">{{ _("AppID") }}</th>
            <th class="datetime started">{{ _("Started") }}</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

**list.js**

```
$(function () {
    var loaders = [];
    var table = $("#portfolio").DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": portfolio_data_url,
            "type": "POST"
        },

        lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],

        "stateSave": true,

        "responsive": true,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "deferRender": true,
        "language": datatables_language,

        "order": [[ $(".portfolio thead th").index($(".portfolio thead .appid")), "desc" ]],

        "columnDefs": [
            {
                "searchable": false,
                "orderable": false,
                "targets": "no-sort"
            }
        ],

        "fnInitComplete": function(){
            $("#portfolio").css("width", "100%");
        }
    })
});
```

I think the problem is in javascript because there is a similar table without a javascript in which the sorting is done correctly.

Comment: You might be using this plug in, if you are this is the solution https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, OP appears to be using the jQuery [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) plugin.

You are just passing the wrong values into the `order` option. Try:

```
[[ $(".portfolio thead th").index($(".portfolio thead .started")), "desc" ]]
```

Or, a simpler:

```
[[ 1 /*Sort by column index-1 (column 2)*/, "desc" ]]
```

Comment: thanks, but  it does not sort alphabetically.
When I applied your code, in the column the vendor records were sorted as follows: "rty" - "asd" - "perl" - "zolo"

Comment: The first number (the 1 in my example) is the column you want to sort by. If you want to sort by a different column, change that number.

Comment: Sorts the correct column number, but the contents of the column are sorted incorrectly